# Support for document sets in Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Is there any developer support for the new "Document Sets" option in BIM 360 Docs - Document Management?
I'd like to organize specific versions of documents into “Sets” in an app that integrates with Forge.
If there isn't, when do you plan to make this possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunate this is not yet supported, we're looking into it as a future improvement.